# Converting code to python 3 where str and bytes can't be concatenated anymore

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert this code to be used in Python 3 but can't figure out how to make it work with concat no longer existing between int and byte objects. 
Edit: that works but causes a new error here it the link to the full file:https://github.com/ndye/tiboyce/blob/master/conv_skin.py

Mainly the error now is after the data is all in memory and waiting to be written it is giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conv_skin2.py", line 42, in <module>
    to_append = ',' * comma + '$%02X' % ord(byte)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

```
def compress(data):
    return chr(len(data) % 256) + chr(len(data) / 256) \
        + lzf.compress(data)
```

Comment: Strings are strings, and bytes are bytes. In your script, you should basically never use strings, and always `bytes`, because you're not working with text, but with binary image data. Therefore, prefix all your string literals with a `b`, i.e. `palette = b''`, etc..

Comment: Please don't substantially change the question after someone has taken the time to answer your original question. If the nature of the problem has changed, accept a solution and ask a new question in a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert a string into bytes before concatenation:

```
def compress(data):
    return (chr(len(data) % 256) + chr(len(data) / 256)).encode('latin1') \
        + lzf.compress(data)
```

See [How to cast a string to bytes without encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795042/how-to-cast-a-string-to-bytes-without-encoding)

Comment: That works but causes a new error here it the link to the full file:https://github.com/ndye/tiboyce/blob/master/conv_skin.py